# meaning of "I'm so in my head"

Tags: expressions

Does the phrase "I'm so in my head", that I have heard in multiple songs, have a special meaning?

Comment: It is not a set phrase in English.  The song lyrics might provide enough  context to determine what the songwriter intended it to mean.  But as it stands one can only speculate about that.  In its current form this  question cannot be definitively answered and should be closed.

Comment: Low-level  English for "That's the way I feel, that's the way I think".

Comment: @Jim, "In one's own head" is a common enough set phrase in some places. It's not quite "In one's head", but then it doesn't have to fit a song's meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely means that a person is being [Introspective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introspection) defined by merriam-webster as:

> the process of examining your own thoughts or feelings

An example of this in a sentence could be

"I had trouble concentrating on the movie because I was 'in my own head' about the fight I had with my father earlier in the day."